# Binding a RichTextBox to a Slider Control in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, scaletransform

I have the following XAML code that I want to perform in xaml.cs.

```
<RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}"
                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}"/>
</RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
```

Basically it binds the slider to the richtextbox and performs zooming.

The following is what i have attempted:

```
RichTextBox newtext = new RichTextBox();
ScaleTransform mytran = new ScaleTransform();
mytran.ScaleX = mySlider.Value;
mytran.ScaleY = mySlider.Value;
newtext.LayoutTransform = mytran;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code behind is equivalent to the Xaml

```
//<RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
//    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}"
//                    ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}"/>
//</RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>

ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();
Binding scaleXBinding = new Binding("Value");
scaleXBinding.Source = mySlider;
Binding scaleYBinding = new Binding("Value");
scaleYBinding.Source = mySlider;
BindingOperations.SetBinding(scaleTransform,
                             ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty,
                             scaleXBinding);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(scaleTransform,
                             ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty,
                             scaleYBinding);

RichTextBox newText = new RichTextBox();
newText.LayoutTransform = scaleTransform;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're asking how to perform the binding in code, or how to set the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties in the code (e.g., without binding). If this is the case, here's how you'd do it:

First, give your `ScaleTransform` a name, e.g. "`myScaleTransform`":

```
<RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
   <ScaleTransform x:Name="myScaleTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
</RichTextBox.LayoutTransform>
```

Then, add an event handler for the [`ValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.valuechanged.aspx) event of `mySlider`. In this handler, update the `ScaleX` and `ScaleY` properties of `myScaleTransform`:

```
public void mySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    myScaleTransform.ScaleX = mySlider.Value;
    myScaleTransform.ScaleY = mySlider.Value;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you did set the transform but not the binding - it will be fixed.
You need to use something like

```
Binding scaleBinding = new Binding("Value"){ElementName="mySlider"};
BindingOperations.SetBinding(mytran, ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, scaleBinding);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(mytran, ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, scaleBinding);
```

to really to the same